# Zend Studio 6.0 or 7.1 svn export only files from a revision number

Tags: svn, export, zend-studio

I am trying to export files from Zend Studio's "SVN Repositories" perspective that belong to a revision number, but the studio exports all the files form other revision number as well.

Maybe this is because the target directory is empty. Can anyone help me on how to export files from one revision number only, not all?

Answer (score 0):

Try `svn export -r<number> <path you want to export to>` on the command line. The svn info is still kept in the project path even if you're using Zend so you still have access to the svn utils via the command line.

Comment: sorry! I don't have much experience with svn. I have got svn also installed mon my local machine. The command line picks up the svn syntax from there. I tried svn export -r21 http://localhost/svn/SVNProj C:\folder , it did everything. Didn't get "The svn info is still kept in the project" how will the command line know about Zend. There is no ENV var for it

Comment: Oh, because the ENV doesn't matter. If you look at your source directory you'll find a bunch of .svn folders which hold all the metadata necessary to run `svn up` or whatever svn commands you want to run. 

Sounds like you got svn export to work though. :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Chuck, I found a bit easier way through Tortoise SVN where I go to the log and select the versions and gives me a comparison by showing the files between versions which I can then select and copy it anywhere

Answer (score 0):

Mirroring your process, I see no export functionality FROM the repository itself. If you want to export a file, return to the PHP or ZF perspective. You'll need to have the desired revision file set checked out locally.

From there, right-click on the file targeted for export and select "Export". You'll receive an Export Wizard which will guide you through the process. Hope that helps.

Good luck.